# Require Auth not getting context value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, react-context

I am trying to send the user to login page for some special pages if he is not logged in. I am using `react-router`. Here is my `RequireAuth` component:

```
const RequireAuth = ({ children }) => {
  const { email, loading } = useContext(LoginRegisterContext);
  console.log(email);
  console.log(children.props);

  let location = useLocation();
  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  if (!email) {
    return <Navigate to="/loginregister" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  } else return children;
};
```

I have created this context to share the values among the components:

```
export const LoginRegisterContext = createContext({});

export function LoginRegisterContextProvider({ children }) {
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
  const [email, setEmail] = useState(null);
  const [password, setPassword] = useState(null);
  const [id, setId] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  console.log(id, email);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchOwner = async () => {
      await axios
        .get("/api/v1/user/ownerprofile", { withCredentials: true })
        .then((res) => {
          setEmail(res.data.email);
          setId(res.data._id);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
        .finally(setLoading(false));
    };
    fetchOwner();
  }, []);

  return (
    <LoginRegisterContext.Provider
      value={{ setEmail, setPassword, setId, id, email, loading }}
    >
      {children}
    </LoginRegisterContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Lastly this is my App.js routes to protect the pages with `RequireAuth` components. Still the `email` is 'null'. But the `loading` variable gets `false` on console. Means I am getting the `loading` variable but not the `email`.

```
<Route
  path="/ownerprofile"
  element={
    <LoginRegisterContextProvider>
      <RequireAuth>
        <OwnerProfile></OwnerProfile>
      </RequireAuth>
    </LoginRegisterContextProvider>
  }
></Route>
```

My loginRegister page code:

```
const LoginRegister = () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("login");

  const {
    setEmail: setLoggedEmail,
    setId,
    id,
    email: loggedEmail,
  } = useContext(LoginRegisterContext);

  let from = location.state?.from?.pathname || "";

  const handleEmail = (ev) => {
    setEmail(ev.target.value);
  };

  const handlePass = (ev) => {
    setPassword(ev.target.value);
    console.log(password);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    await axios
      .post(
        status === "register" ? "api/v1/user/register" : "api/v1/user/login",
        {
          email: email,
          password: password,
        },
        { withCredentials: true }
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setLoggedEmail(res.data.email);
        setId(res.data.id);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
  };

  console.log(loggedEmail);

  if (loggedEmail) {
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
  }
```

Comment: Is there an error in `fetchOwner` during the axios call and Promise chain? That's the only way I see `email` remaining null. Why is `email` a dependency in the `useEffect` when the hook is updating *that* state? Is the app code render looping? Also, do no other routes need the auth check, just `"/ownerprofile"` needs it?

Comment: @DrewReese there is no error on axios call. email is found on other components except RequireAuth. I have cleared the dependency. The app code is render looping when i am using this snippet on loginRegister page.  ` if (loggedEmail) {
    navigate(from, { replace: true });
  }`. But this snippet allows to manually view the protected page with direct url. without this snippet it always showing login page even if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've at least a couple issues in the code, in the `useEffect` hook in the provider.

1. The `useEffect` hook incorrectly includes `email` in its dependency array when `email` is the state the effect updates. It should be removed.
2. The `finally` block is immediately invoking the `setLoading` state. This means the context isn't able to correctly provide the `loading` state value to the context consumers. `finally` should be passed a callback function.

The `useEffect` hook also had a useless snippet of code that checked if the `email` was truthy and just enqueued a state update to the current value. This also should be removed.

An additional note, it's generally considered an anti-pattern to mix `async/await` and Promise chains. Select one or the other. Here's I've kept the Promise chain you were using and removed the `async/await` since it wasn't doing anything for you.

Example:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchOwner = () => {
    axios
      .get("/api/v1/user/ownerprofile", { withCredentials: true })
      .then((res) => {
        setEmail(res.data.email);
        setId(res.data._id);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false)); // <-- callback
  };

  fetchOwner();
}, []); // <-- empty dependency
```

[image: Edit require-auth-not-getting-context-value]